# Installing lsyncd on 64bit Amazon Ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, fedora

I am trying to install lsyncd (http://code.google.com/p/lsyncd/) on my Amazon EC2, Amaozn Linux AMI 64bit.  And during the make process I am reciving this error which I cannot decrypt.  It installed no problem in 32bit version on the AMI but 64bit instance is giving me issues.  Any one know what I am doing wrong? Here is the error message:

```
[root@xx-xx-xx-xx lsyncd-2.0.4]# ./configure && make && make install
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for LUA... no
checking for LUA... no
checking for LUA... no
checking for LUA... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking sys/inotify.h usability... yes
checking sys/inotify.h presence... yes
checking for sys/inotify.h... yes
compiling with inotify
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/lsyncd-2.0.4'
gcc  -g -O2 -Wall    -o lsyncd lsyncd.o inotify.o /usr/lib64/liblua.a luac.o 
/usr/lib64/liblua.a(lvm.o): In function `Arith':
(.text+0xa75): undefined reference to `pow'
/usr/lib64/liblua.a(lvm.o): In function `Arith':
(.text+0xaa4): undefined reference to `floor'
/usr/lib64/liblua.a(lvm.o): In function `luaV_execute':
(.text+0x2287): undefined reference to `floor'
/usr/lib64/liblua.a(lvm.o): In function `luaV_execute':
(.text+0x2362): undefined reference to `pow'
/usr/lib64/liblua.a(lcode.o): In function `codearith':
(.text+0x11b5): undefined reference to `pow'
/usr/lib64/liblua.a(lcode.o): In function `codearith':
(.text+0x11e3): undefined reference to `floor'
/usr/lib64/liblua.a(lmathlib.o): In function `math_tan':
(.text+0x12f): undefined reference to `tan'
/usr/lib64/liblua.a(lmathlib.o): In function `math_tanh':
(.text+0x15f): undefined reference to `tanh'
/usr/lib64/liblua.a(lmathlib.o): In function `math_sqrt':
(.text+0x1a3): undefined reference to `sqrt'
/usr/lib64/liblua.a(lmathlib.o): In function `math_sin':
(.text+0x1cf): undefined reference to `sin'
/usr/lib64/liblua.a(lmathlib.o): In function `math_sinh':
(.text+0x1ff): undefined reference to `sinh'
/usr/lib64/liblua.a(lmathlib.o): In function `math_floor':
(.text+0x32f): undefined reference to `floor'
/usr/lib64/liblua.a(lmathlib.o): In function `math_random':
(.text+0x44e): undefined reference to `floor'
/usr/lib64/liblua.a(lmathlib.o): In function `math_random':
(.text+0x496): undefined reference to `floor'
/usr/lib64/liblua.a(lmathlib.o): In function `math_pow':
(.text+0x51a): undefined reference to `pow'
/usr/lib64/liblua.a(lmathlib.o): In function `math_log':
(.text+0x59f): undefined reference to `log'
/usr/lib64/liblua.a(lmathlib.o): In function `math_log10':
(.text+0x5cf): undefined reference to `log10'
/usr/lib64/liblua.a(lmathlib.o): In function `math_fmod':
(.text+0x70d): undefined reference to `fmod'
/usr/lib64/liblua.a(lmathlib.o): In function `math_exp':
(.text+0x72f): undefined reference to `exp'
/usr/lib64/liblua.a(lmathlib.o): In function `math_cos':
(.text+0x75f): undefined reference to `cos'
/usr/lib64/liblua.a(lmathlib.o): In function `math_cosh':
(.text+0x78f): undefined reference to `cosh'
/usr/lib64/liblua.a(lmathlib.o): In function `math_ceil':
(.text+0x7bf): undefined reference to `ceil'
/usr/lib64/liblua.a(lmathlib.o): In function `math_atan':
(.text+0x7ef): undefined reference to `atan'
/usr/lib64/liblua.a(lmathlib.o): In function `math_atan2':
(.text+0x83a): undefined reference to `atan2'
/usr/lib64/liblua.a(lmathlib.o): In function `math_asin':
(.text+0x86f): undefined reference to `asin'
/usr/lib64/liblua.a(lmathlib.o): In function `math_acos':
(.text+0x89f): undefined reference to `acos'
/usr/lib64/liblua.a(loadlib.o): In function `ll_loadfunc':
(.text+0x8d8): undefined reference to `dlsym'
/usr/lib64/liblua.a(loadlib.o): In function `ll_loadfunc':
(.text+0x931): undefined reference to `dlopen'
/usr/lib64/liblua.a(loadlib.o): In function `ll_loadfunc':
(.text+0x949): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/lib64/liblua.a(loadlib.o): In function `ll_loadfunc':
(.text+0x960): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/lib64/liblua.a(loadlib.o): In function `gctm':
(.text+0xe9c): undefined reference to `dlclose'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [lsyncd] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/lsyncd-2.0.4'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have libm installed ? This relate to LibMath.

It should be included in glibc-static package on Fedora (as mentionned in your Tags).

Comment: It was installing glibc-static.  That fixed it.  Thank you!